# Android Open GL ES 2.0 - What are the requirements for Vertex Array Objects (VAO)?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

What are the requirements to be able to use Vertex Array Objects?
I know that some GPUs support it and some do not. I'm wondering if there are certain additional requirements to be met when compiling.

Is there a minimum Android SDK version that needs to be used?

What values are the minimum for compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in Gradle (Android Studio) ?

What is the minimum Android version that needs to be installed on the device?

Or does it maybe not matter at all and either the GPU supports it or not?

Comment: In any case, you'll need to check at runtime for the presence of `GL_OES_vertex_array_object`, resolve the corresponding entry points and use them. That should be pretty independent from the Android version.

Comment: Yes, I'm checking at runtime if it's available (Cocos2d-x does that automatically and saves it). I'm just wondering if there's any additional requirement when compiling.

Comment: It's an optional extension, you need to check it's a GPU driver thing. Nothing to do with Android above needing OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: Okay, and also never Android version do not update this driver? Or compiling against a newer android version can not add this extension?

Comment: It depends on the graphics driver on the platform. As above it's nothing to do with Android.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, API 9 introduced openGL ES 2.0. On startup in the onCreate method just add:

```
// Check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0.

final ActivityManager activityManager =
        (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo =
        activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

if (!supportsEs2)
{
    Log.i("WLGFX","Device does not support OpenGL ES 2.0");
    System.exit(-1);
    return;
}
```

It's also been a long time since I last looked at VAO's, I actually thought they got rid of them completely. For performance, use VBO's. They're just as easy to create and use. Here's some sample snippets:

```
void FFDisplay::init_texture_buffers() {    // for overlay screen
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
            -1.0f,  -1.0f,      0.0f,   1.0f,   // X, Y, U, V
            -1.0f,   1.0f,      0.0f,   0.0f,
            1.0f,    1.0f,      1.0f,   0.0f,
            1.0f,   -1.0f,      1.0f,   1.0f
    };

    GLushort indices[] = { 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3 };

    glGenBuffers(2, texture_buffers);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture_buffers[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 64, vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture_buffers[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12, indices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    texture_texture = 0;
}

void FFDisplay::init_overlay_texture() {
    glGenTextures(1, &overlay_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, overlay_texture);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_HINT, GL_FALSE );
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, FFD_OVERLAY_WID, FFD_OVERLAY_HGT,
                 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, overlay_image);
}

void FFDisplay::draw_overlay() {
    glUseProgram(prog_texture);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, overlay_texture);

    glUniform1i(texture_texture, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texture_vertex);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texture_uv);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture_buffers[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, texture_buffers[1]);

    glVertexAttribPointer(texture_vertex, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 16, NULL);
    glVertexAttribPointer(texture_uv, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 16, (void*)8);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(texture_uv);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(texture_vertex);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

There's tons of information on GLES 2.0 out there to get you started.

Comment: This is completely wrong. VAOs are not available in ES 2.0 (except as an extension), and were only introduced in ES 3.0. It looks like you might be confusing them with client-side vertex arrays. Those are very different things.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of the old client-side vertex arrays which is why I mentioned VBO's.